# Hugging Face Evaluator Module - Evaluation Speed seems very slow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I've been learning how to fine-train HuggingFace text classification models using their tutorials and some other information online.

So far I've managed to train a model on a custom dataset - import as dataframe, then convert to datasets object with train and test splits and then converted to a tensorflow dataset object using `model.prepare_tf_dataset`. My dataset has two labels - true and false.

So far it seems to work and I can see a variety of metrics - accuracy, recall, f1 - in Tensorboard using the HuggingFace metrics callbacks. However, it seems that these only apply to the training dataset, but I'd like to see these for the validation dataset after the model has trained.

Looking at their tutorials again, they have the Evaluator class and have this code which seems to do what I need.

Code:

```
# 3. Pass an instantiated pipeline
pipe = pipeline("text-classification", model="lvwerra/distilbert-imdb")

eval_results = task_evaluator.compute(
    model_or_pipeline=pipe,
    data=data,
    label_mapping={"NEGATIVE": 0, "POSITIVE": 1}
)
print(eval_results)
```

Output:

```
{
    'accuracy': 0.918,
    'latency_in_seconds': 0.013,
    'samples_per_second': 78.887,
    'total_time_in_seconds': 12.676
}
```

Running this specific code takes about 7 minutes with the Google Colab V100 GPU. On my own dataset - where the test dataset is about 3k rows - it takes significantly longer (not 100% sure yet as it hasn't finished).

Am I doing something wrong here, or is there a way to speed this up?

Sorry if I'm not clear or missing info, I'm still quite new to this. But in summary, I'd like the accuracy, recall, f1 metrics when I apply my model to the test set of data so that I can evaluate it's predictive performance.

It might be worth mentioning that I haven't used the trainer class for this.